# Running a code in background

Tags: android, file-io, intentservice, android-intentservice

I am developing an application where I have to take input through USB and display and plot it on different screens. I am using TabView for display and plotting on different screens. The problem is that the data which is coming from the USB needs to be saved in a file. I am thinking that is there some means by which I can run a code in background which will take the input from the USB and write it in the file and even when I am switching between different screens, the background work continues to happen?

I have read about IntentService but I am not sure if it can help with what I need.

Comment: Yes use IntentService but Service would be a better choice

Answer (score 1):

To run code in background you have to use [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
Here's some tutorials :

- [Creating a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_an_Android_Started_Service_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example
- http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/android-simple-service/

Hope it helps !